# Rename dojo.js after/during build

Tags: javascript, dojo

I created a single dojo.js file using the following steps:

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/

```
layers: {
            "dojo/dojo": {
                include: [ "dojo/dojo", "dojo/i18n", "dojo/domReady",
                    "app/main", "app/run" ],
                customBase: true,
                boot: true
            },
            "app/Dialog": {
                include: [ "app/Dialog" ]
            }
        }
```

I am running the build using MAVEN.

How can I change the name of dojo.js to dojo-1.0.0_abc.js ??

Is there any parameter in build.sh which i can specify to change dojo.js to dojo.1.0.0.js??

Comment: Is renaming that single JS file really what you want to do?  Dojo is generally not represented by a single JS file; at the very least you are likely to also need to load an NLS resource and a theme stylesheet, and the build creates an entire release folder, so should you be seeking to version the entire release instead?

Comment: Thats what I was thinking later. I added versioning to the folder :) Thanks though.